# Recordset Not updateable for checkbox

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, recordset

In my database I have 1 table - (tbl_RTILog)

I have 1 form that enters the data into this table - (frm_Logger)

I then have a separate form that would update the checkbox in the table - (frm_RTIRev).

My table fields are:

ID - Autonumber

Acc Number - number

MPRN - number

Time Raised - time

Sweep Time - time

Advisor - text

Credit - currency

PayID - text

Reviewer - text

Completed? yes/no

I have a recordset as below in the record source, `SELECT tbl_RTILog.[Account Number], tbl_RTILog.MPRN, tbl_RTILog.[Time Raised], tbl_RTILog.[Expected Sweep Time], tbl_RTILog.Advisor, tbl_RTILog.[Credit Amount], tbl_RTILog.[Paypoint ID], tbl_RTILog.[Completed?], tbl_RTILog.ID FROM tbl_RTILog WHERE (((tbl_RTILog.[Completed?])=False)) GROUP BY tbl_RTILog.[Account Number], tbl_RTILog.MPRN, tbl_RTILog.[Time Raised], tbl_RTILog.[Expected Sweep Time], tbl_RTILog.Advisor, tbl_RTILog.[Credit Amount], tbl_RTILog.[Paypoint ID], tbl_RTILog.[Completed?], tbl_RTILog.ID ORDER BY tbl_RTILog.[Time Raised] DESC;` 
This is filtering the data to only show records where the checkbox returns 'False'.

I have tried changing the recordset type from 'Dynaset' to 'Dynaset (inconsistent updates) and this has made no difference.

All I want to do is for the second form to load (frm_RTIRev) and display all incomplete reviews and then be able to be marked as completed but the 'recordset is no updateable'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to answer my own question in some weird and wonderful unexplainable way.

I recreated the Query and this allowed me to edit the data.

No answer for this apart from that when I remade it it worked straight away.